# MySQL datetime is not stored as UTC, but in server time zone

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timezone

MySQL database: store Java Date into database column of `DATETIME` type, e.g.,

```
   Table Foo
   -----------------------
   id         |  time
   -----------------------
   bigint(20)   datetime
```

The date is

```
01/15/19 19:00:00 (Time Zone: UTC+1:00),

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss');
df.setTimeZone("Europe/Paris");   // UTC+1:00
Date date = df.parse("01/15/19 19:00:00");

PreparedStatement st = new PreparedStatement("insert into Foo (id, time) values (?, ?)";
st.setObject(1, 1);
st.setObject(2, date);
st.executeUpdate();
```

which is expected to be converted into

```
01/15/19 18:00:00 UTC
```

and stored in database.

MySQL time zone is `SYSTEM (UTC-6:00)`. JVM time zone is `UTC-6:00`. Both are running in the same machine. The value stored is `01/15/19 12:00:00`. Why is it stored in Server time zone (not UTC)?

An SQL query `SELECT time FROM Foo;` gives the following result:

```
time
-------------------
2019-01-15 12:00:00
```

Changing server time zone did not affect the select value.

```
mysql> set time_zone='+8:00';

select time from Foo;

    time
    -------------------
    2019-01-15 12:00:00
```

Comment: What is your client time zone?

Comment: mysql client? select @@time_zone: SYSTEM. the system time zone is UTC-6:00.

Comment: what exactly does the insert look like?

Comment: What is the datatype of your database column? When my memory serves me right, MySQL has a `timestamp with timezone` datatype that will ensure that timestamps are stored in UTC.

Comment: @DanFarrell updated.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes, never `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
myPreparedStatement                   // With JDBC 4.2, wa can directly exchange java.time objects with the database.
.setObject(                           // Pass a `OffsetDateTime` object representing the moment we want stored in the database.
    LocalDateTime.parse(              // Parse the input string lacking an indicator of offset or zone.
        "2019-01-19T19:00"            // When using strings in standard ISO 8601 format, no need to specify a formatting pattern.
    )                                 // Returns a `LocalDateTime`, an ambiguous value without real meaning.
    .atZone(                          // Apply a time zone to give meaning to the `LocalDateTime`. 
        ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" )   // Here we are saying "the 7 PM on that date as seen on the clock on the wall of someone standing in Paris France".
    )                                 // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toOffsetDateTime()               // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object as demanded by the JDBC spec, stripping off the time zone to leave on the hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.
)
```

## java.time

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. There is really no point in trying to debug/understand the legacy classes, as they are bloody awful mess.

## `LocalDateTime`

Parse your input string as a `LocalDateTime` as it lacks any indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Make a habit of using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for date-time text whenever possible. For a date with time-of-day, what would be YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS where the `T` separates the date-portion from the time-portion.

```
String input = "2019-01-19T19:00" ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ; // No need to specify formatting pattern when using standard ISO 8601 formats.
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

The `LocalDateTime` class too lacks any concept of zone or offset. So an object of this class does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. It represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the various time zones around the globe.

You seem to know for certain this date and time were meant to represent a moment in a particular time zone. So apply a time zone, to give meaning to our ambiguous `LocalDateTime` object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Now we can apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your JDBC *may* be accept the `ZonedDateTime` object, but the JDBC 4.2 spec requires that it take an `OffsetDateTime`. What's the difference? Both `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` represent a moment, a point on the timeline. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead-of or behind UTC. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. So a time zone is always preferable. Except here, where we are using JDBC to exchange a *java.time* object with the database, we use `OffsetDateTime` to write standard code.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;  // Convert from moment with time zone to a moment with merely an offset-from-UTC.
```

Now we can pass this moment to your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement( … , odt ) ;  // Pass a `OffsetDateTime` moment as the value for a placeholder in the SQL of your prepared statement.
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Assign the desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Both the `odt` and `zdt` seen in the few lines above represent the very same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline. Only their wall-clock time is different, as most databases store and retrieve UTC while you want to see Paris time.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).